I Have Imagination of Futuristic Computing Scenarios. How Can I Get Involved?
I am currently a backend developer specializing in Java-oriented web services, with a bachelor's degree in Computer Science. After working for a few years, I have become deeply interested in diving into a technical research direction that aligns with future computing paradigms. Specifically, I am fascinated by two scenarios:
Scenario 1: Real-time, Movable Compute Resource Access
I envision a future where compute power can be accessed in real-time from nearby sources, enabling mobile and dynamic compute capabilities, just like today's mobile network power. This scenario emphasizes the need for efficient scheduling, low-latency network communication, and real-time data processing.
Scenario 2: Compute Resource Sharing and Leasing from Personal Devices
This involves formatting compute resources from personal devices for shared use and leasing, requiring abstraction and virtualization for computing power. I think this might be really hard to achieve.
My Interest
While I am interested in these futuristic scenarios, I am particularly focused on research that deals with scheduling, resource management, and application-level solutions, rather than hardware-level issues such as network communication.
Request for Guidance
I would greatly appreciate your insights on the following:

What are the key research directions and current trends in these areas? Which keywords should I search for?
What foundational knowledge and skills should I acquire to start exploring these topics?
For someone considering a shift towards academic research or a PhD in these fields, what would you advise?

Thank you for your time and assistance. I am eager to contribute to the future of computing and deeply value your guidance.
p.s. My English isn’t very good, thus I have GPT polish the words.
